# Git remote tags aren't staying deleted

Tags: git, tags

We are attempting to delete some tags on our remote git server that were mistakenly added, but they don't seem to want to stay deleted. I'm deleting with

```
git tag -d 12345
git push origin :refs/tags/12345
```

Then I've instructed all team members to immediately run a git fetch and git fetch --tags to update their locals. I suspected that people may have been pushing before fetching, thus pushing back up tags from their local that should have been deleted, except after going through this a couple times, the remote tags are still showing back up.

Is there some step we are missing?

Comment: `git fetch --tags` won't prune tags. Judging by [git-fetch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) you might have to run `git fetch --prune refs/tags/*` or similar. I suggest you don't bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

Might try:

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```